# Trying to copy data from one tab to another using Query

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to copy a line of data from one tab to another based upon the Expiration Date Column; I want to copy if it is within 2 weeks.  But cannot figure out whaty is wrong on the syntax.

```
=query('Badge Data'!A1:G, "select * where (G<today()+15)",1)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

RDL, dates in QUERYs are a little tricky. Try this:

```
=QUERY('Badge Data'!A:G, "Select * Where G Is Not Null And G < date '"&TEXT(TODAY()+15,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)
```

Comment: Great, RDL. Would you mark my answer as the Best/Accepted answer so that other techs know this issue has been resolved? Thanks.